# How to define Shfit+Ctrl keybinding?

Tags: key-bindings, doom

I can't seem to press `S-C-c` - it gets registered as `C-c`...

[image]

Why? I can't even think of any reason why this type of situation would come about?

UPDATE: it seems like evil vim keybindings are to blame...
I still can't think of any reason why this type of behaviour would take place ever ever: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506764/how-to-map-ctrla-and-ctrlshifta-differently

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by following this guide: https://discourse.doomemacs.org/t/how-to-re-bind-keys/56

`(map! "S-C-c" #'clipboard-kill-ring-save)`

Update above was irrelevant. Lord have mercy on any future soul trying to understand emacs keybidings...